# Can it possible to render the User Edit page in liferay portlet?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I got a requirement that the site admin wants to create a users under his site and need to view only his site users. So I have created a portlet and deployed it under site_administration.users.

I have the following queries,

1) Now In my portlet I need to show the user creation form (users_admin/edit_user.jsp) layout. Now Is there any way to use the existing user add/ edit source OR Do I need to create the form from the scratch?

2) Also How can we restrict that the site admin can only view users under his site?

Any suggestions OR References are required. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior can be achieved in Liferay 6.2 without a custom portlet. You would simply add a custom role (a regular role), and define the proper permissions so that anyone with this role can add users. You need to configure the permissions so that this Role can access the Control Panel and Add Users. More information can be found here: https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/roles-and-permissions

One thing to note, the Site Admin will be able to add users to the portal, and be able to assign them to his/her site, or another site. Once added to the portal, they can also be added to the site in Site Administration.

Comment: Great but the problem is If I do like this, the site admin is able to view the users of other sites too. But I don't want this actually. The site admin wants to view only his users.